# Redirect to a different page in a new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager, response.redirect

I'm trying to give the user a new browser window and redirect them to a different page. I've done it before using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(string), "popup","window.open('ClaimTimeExpense.aspx', '_blank')", true);
```

The thing with this is that the current page that I'm on has a URL/file path of for example,

localhost/protected/ADMIN/AllUsers.aspx

but the page I need to redirect to is just

localhost/protected/myPage2.aspx

so when the window open up it throws server error because it's puttin the file path to..

localhost/protected/ADMIN/ClaimTimeExpense.aspx

Is there something wrong in my script manager line or any way to get the url to point correctly?  I would use javascript but it's required to be this way.

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly, but couldn't you just use a ../ in front of the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one so as to open localhost/protected/myPage2.aspx:

```
window.open('../ClaimTimeExpense.aspx', '_blank')
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it. I'll approve as soon as it lets me.